# Is it safe to "finally" drop a table just after a fetchall with psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Give a cursor variable curr over a connection conn, is it safe to "finally" drop a table after fetching all results from it? Something like the following

```
curr.execute(some_select_query)

try:
    results = curr.fetchall()
except:
    some_error_handling()
finally:
    curr.execute(drop_table_query)
    conn.commit()

use_results_array_here
```

Will all results be fetched into the results array already? Is performance affected by the drop there?

Answer (score 1):

yes, all the rows will be fetched as a list of tuples but, maybe, you want to use `else` instead of `finally`

`Else` is executed only if `try` was succesfull, in this way you avoid deleting the table in case of errors during fetching (connection drops, etc...).

```
curr.execute(some_select_query)
try:
    results = curr.fetchall()
except:
    some_error_handling()
else:
    curr.execute(drop_table_query)
    conn.commit()

use_results_array_here
```

Comment: The table is temporary and there is no retry mechanism, however thanks for the suggestion.